# Android Studio Giraffe - Auto complete and other features not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio Giraffe patch 1, but I'm facing issues with the auto-complete features. None of the variable checking, function assistance, or contextual help seems to be functioning. Despite this, I'm able to compile the project, although it does generate errors.

I attempted to troubleshoot the problem by downgrading my compile and target SDK from 33 to 32. However, the issue persists and I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Invalidated the cache and restarted Android Studio.
2. Tried uninstalling Android Studio and then reinstalling it.
3. Deleted the .gradle cache to see if that would resolve the issue.

Unfortunately, none of these steps have yielded any positive results. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or advice in resolving this perplexing issue.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: yes I did reinstall the Android studio - click on file > manage ide settings > restore default setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

1. Reinstall the Android studio Girrafe
2. Click on File > Manage IDE settings > restore default setting
3. install the SDK and everything again it will work

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Flutter Plugins.Please check the attached link https://stackoverflow.com/a/77263167/8348768

Remove the

Flutter Plugins, flutter Provider, Flutter Snippets, Flutter AssetsGenerator, flutter_json_fromat, flutter_Add_image, FlutterJsonBeanFactory from plugins then check if you have those.

After removing the plugin the Suggestion are showing.

Thanks

Comment: please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587