# Suggestions are not working in Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: android, android-studio, autosuggest, android-studio-girafee

I Installed the new Version of Android studio Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2.
I found Variable suggestion is not working.

I have done lots of R&D and they suggested delete the .idea folder and delete the folder on

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3

.
but still not have the proper solution.

Example.

I added the Timer class. I've just write timer. then no suggestion.

[image]

Anyone has any solution for this please post your answer.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: lot of suggestions in this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working

Comment: @Shaleen I've tried but not getting the proper solution.

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal did you try creating a new project and try the suggestion in the new project? Can create a new project, if the suggestion works, then invalidate and restart. It may sound weird, but that had worked for me

Comment: @RahulAgrawal I tried but still no suggestions on the new Project.v

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal what about settings->Editor->General->code completion. Most of the settings related to this are available on that section. Also by any chance any compilation issue in the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I asked the same question to google community and they said

> *Do you have Flutter installed? We have seen a few issues of this sort recently with Android Studio Giraffe that have been caused by Flutter
> exceptions. If you have Flutter installed and the problem only
> reproduces when it is enabled, then please file an issue with the
> Flutter team at
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij#filing-issues. If you Does
> this issue reproduce when Flutter is not enable? If so, please share
> diagnostic logs, which can be found by going to Help > Collect Logs
> and Diagnostic Data. If this issue is related to Flutter, please file
> an issue with the Flutter team at
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij#filing-issues.*

after That I've checked the log diagnostic and found there is some flutter  classes Exception issue on the .log file.
like

> com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot create class com.intellij.codeInsight.template.LiveTemplateContextService

Remove the

Flutter Plugins,
flutter Provider,
Flutter Snippets,
Flutter AssetsGenerator,
flutter_json_fromat,
flutter_Add_image,
FlutterJsonBeanFactory
from plugins then check if you have those.

After removing the plugin the Suggestion are showing.

Thanks

Comment: how did you fix it? I found the same issue and the logs

Comment: @TrungLe Go to setting>Plugins and remove the Flutter Plugins, Flutter Snippets also if you have Flutter Snippets then remove it and check

Comment: it's kinda weird that I downloaded the Preview version (hedgehog) and just ran it like a different version the issue isn't there 
I think probably a full cleanup will work

Comment: I uninstalled these given lists of Flutter's plugins after that, it is working fine for me. :)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the Flutter Snippets plugin from plugins then Restart the studio.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the reported issue and observations around what the issue might be.

From https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6929:

---

I was able to reproduce with the second "Flutter Snippets" extension I tried, i.e. this one:https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15071-flutter-snippets.

Adding/removing the extension does break and then fix the code completions from working. Please reopen this issue or create another one if there is something else breaking code completions in the Flutter & Flutter Plugin for IntelliJ.